# Use ID to display data

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Doctor and Appointment table]

I have two tables; Appointment table and Doctor table. I want to echo the information that is in the Doctor table (Name and Room) into the Appointment table using the Doctor_id. My code so far looks like this

Appointment.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
        <!-- User-generated css -->
        <style>
        </style>
        <!-- User-generated js -->
        <script>
            try {

    $(function() {

    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
  }
        </script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="d" href="login.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                    Back
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"class="ui-btn-right">
                 Home  
                </a>
                <h3>
                    Book appointment
                </h3>
           </div>

           <div data-role="content">
                <h3>
                    Select date/time:
                </h3>
                <br />
     <?php
{
    mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


    $pid=intval($_SESSION["Patient_id"]); $query = "SELECT Appointment_id, Doctor_id, Patient_id, Appointment_time, Appointment_date FROM Appointment where Patient_id=$pid";

    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");
    //this selects the results as rows

    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1) {}
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Appointment_date'] = $row['Appointment_date'];
        $_SESSION['Appointment_time'] = $row['Appointment_time'];
    }
}
?>  

        <strong>Dates available</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Select date--</option>
        <option value="1"><?php echo $_SESSION['Appointment_date'];?></option>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

        <strong>Times available</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Select time--</option>
        <option value="2"><?php echo $_SESSION['Appointment_time'];?></option>>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

                <label for="textarea1">
                Message GP
                </label>
                <textarea name="" id="textarea1" placeholder="">
                </textarea>


             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: So... what is the question? :)

Comment: I want to echo the information that is in the Doctor table (Name and Room) into the Appointment table using the Doctor_id.

Comment: You want to just use the information, not really echo it into the appointment table right ?

Comment: What does that mean? You can't put data into a table if there are no columns for it.

Comment: You need to JOIN the Doctor table with the Appointment table. This is basic SQL stuff.

Comment: @Barmar, there is data in the database. It is linked up.

Comment: @ArchiFloyd, yeah just want to use the information

Comment: I meant you can't put data from the Doctor table into the Appointment table, because the Appointment table doesn't have Name and Room columns.

Comment: Read about joins in any SQL tutorial.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp - think this is a good explanation of it.

Comment: Some credit should also go to Barmar, as he was actually first with the answer, I just provided a place to read about it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a query like this one:

```
selec * from Appointment ap
inner join Doctor doc
on (ap.Doctor_id=doc.Doctor_id)
where ap.Patient_id=$pid
```

Then, this line:

```
$query = "SELECT Appointment_id, Doctor_id, Patient_id, Appointment_time, Appointment_date FROM Appointment where Patient_id=$pid";
```

Should be replaced with this one:

```
$query = "selec * from Appointment ap      
         inner join Doctor doc
         on (ap.Doctor_id=doc.Doctor_id)
         where ap.Patient_id=$pid";
```

Saludos ;)